# Switch between numbers and run function on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, events, scroll

How could I toggle class between these numbers both on click and on scroll..? So, basically I want to switch between these when rotating mouse wheel, and fire some sort of a callback after that...

EDIT: So, I would like to be able to move mouse wheel anywhere in the window, and that would in return toggle class .active in the li's. Also, when for example li#runOne is selected, it should run a callback function let's say runFunctionOne. When li#runTwo is selected/scrolled to - it would run for example runFunctionTwo...

```js
$("#runTwo").on('click', function() {
  $("#runTwo").toggleClass("active", function() {
    // Run some callback
    console.log("Two");
  });
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
  // Switch between numbers on scroll
});
```

```css
ul {
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 300px;
}

.active {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="runOne" class="runOne active">Run 1</li>
  <li id="runTwo" class="runTwo">Run 2</li>
  <li id="runThree" class="runThree">Run 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you please explain more ?? what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Check the answer below - something similar: So, I would like to be able to move mouse wheel anywhere in the window, and that would in return toggle class .active in the li's. Also, when for example li#runOne is selected, it should run a callback function let's say runFunctionOne. When li#runTwo is selected/scrolled to - it would run for example runFunctionTwo...

Answer (score 1):

You can toggle class using click and mousewheel like this

https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/rKOBEq

```
$('.rr').on('click, mousewheel', function() {
          $('.rr').removeClass('active');
         $(this).addClass('active');
            console.log("Two");
});
```

Comment: Nice...thanks. Is it maybe possible to scroll anywhere on the body, but switch class only inside the ul? So, exactly the same behaviour with clicking on the <li>, but scroll anywhere and still toggle classes on li's?

Answer (score 1):

HTML code:

```
<ul>
   <li id="runOne" class="runOne active list">Run 1</li>
   <li id="runTwo" class="runTwo list">Run 2</li>
   <li id="runThree" class="runThree list">Run 3</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery code:

```
$('.list').click(function(e){
  $('.list.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active').trigger('activeEvent');
});
$(document).on('mousewheel',function(e){
  var currentScrollAmt=$(window).scrollTop();
  var activeLi=$('.list.active');
   $('.list.active').removeClass('active');

  if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta /120 > 0) {
       //Scrolling Up
   if(!activeLi.is(':first-child'))
      activeLi.prev('li').addClass('active').trigger('activeEvent');
    }
    else{
        //Scrolling Down
      if(!activeLi.is(':last-child'))
      activeLi.next('li').addClass('active').trigger('activeEvent');
    }  
});
$('li').on('activeEvent',function(e){
 runCallback(e.target.id);
});
function runCallback(id)
{
  if(!id)
    return false;
  switch(id)
  {
     case 'runOne':
       alert('runOne Callback Code');
       break;
     case 'runTwo':
       alert('runTwo Callback Code');
       break;
     case 'runThree':
        alert('runThree Callback Code');
         break;
 }
}
```

Comment: Very nice, thanks for your effort... However there is an issue, if you keep scrolling past the last item, the .active class disappears and nothing is triggered after that